# Need help in toggling the class of a span when a radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I've a problem with toggling the class of a `<span>` when one of the radio buttons is clicked.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<style type="text/css">
    .eHide
    {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change()
    {
        var NAME = document.getElementById("return");
        var currentClass = NAME.className;
        if (currentClass == "eHide") { // Check the current class name
            NAME.className = "";   // Set other class name
        } else {
            NAME.className = "eHide";  // Otherwise, use `second_name`
        }
    }

    function disp()
    {
        document.getElementById("spanfrom").innerHTML = document.getElementById("from").value;
        document.getElementById("spanto").innerHTML = document.getElementById("to").value;
        document.getElementById("spandate").innerHTML = document.getElementById("departure").value;
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div style="width: 1000px">
        <div id="innerWrapper"  style="position:relative;left:50px;top:20px;">
            <div>
                From: <input type="text" id="from" placeholder="Source"/>
                <span style="float:right">To: <input type="text" id="to" placeholder="Destination"/></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                Depart Date: <input type="text" id="departure" placeholder="Departure"/>
                <span style="float:right">Return: <input type="text" id="return" placeholder="Return"/></span>
            </div>

            <div id="control">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" value="oneWayRadio" onClick="change();"> One Way
                <input type="radio" name="radio" value="returnRadio"  checked onClick="change();"> Return
                <button value="Submit" onClick="disp()" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>

            <div class="text">You are going from <span id="spanfrom"></span> to  <span id="spanto"></span> on <span id="spandate"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my entire code, the problem is of a ticket reservation form, where there are two radio buttons, "One Way" and "Return". When I click "One Way", the `<input>` tag with `id="return"` should be hidden and that's working. But the span around it which contains the word "Return" is not getting hidden. You might say I could just use id="return" on the `<span>` instead of `<input>` but I'm not supposed to.

The possible solution I thought of was, in the function change() I'm getting the element using it's ID "return", is it possible to get the span instead of input? And I'm not allowed to use JQuery. Only pure JavaScript should be used.

Comment: Why don't you just put the "return" ID on the whole wrapping span? `<span style="float:right"  id="return">Return: <input type="text" placeholder="Return"/></span>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parentElement](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp) property, like this

```
var returnSpanElement = document.getElementById("return").parentElement;
```

Comment: Thank you @Sergey, works perfectly. I even tried using parentNode and it does the same job.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
<html>
<head></head>
<style type="text/css">
    .eHide
    {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change()
    {
        var NAME = document.getElementById("return").parentNode;
        var currentClass = NAME.className;
        if (currentClass == "eHide") { 
            NAME.className = "";   
        } else {
            NAME.className = "eHide";
        }
    }

    function disp()
    {
        document.getElementById("spanfrom").innerHTML = document.getElementById("from").value;
        document.getElementById("spanto").innerHTML = document.getElementById("to").value;
        document.getElementById("spandate").innerHTML = document.getElementById("departure").value;
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div style="width: 1000px">
        <div id="innerWrapper"  style="position:relative;left:50px;top:20px;">
            <div>
                From: <input type="text" id="from" placeholder="Source"/>
                <span style="float:right">To: <input type="text" id="to" placeholder="Destination"/></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                Depart Date: <input type="text" id="departure" placeholder="Departure"/>
                <span style="float:right">Return: <input type="text" id="return" placeholder="Return"/></span>
            </div>

            <div id="control">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" value="oneWayRadio" onClick="change();"> One Way
                <input type="radio" name="radio" value="returnRadio"  checked onClick="change();"> Return
                <button value="Submit" onClick="disp()" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>

            <div class="text">You are going from <span id="spanfrom"></span> to  <span id="spanto"></span> on <span id="spandate"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```